# Why does TRY_CAST throw an error when attempting to convert VARCHAR to UNIQUEIDENTIFIER?

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I have a VARCHAR(MAX) column in a table that can store data in many different formats, including the GUID format. I tried the following code when joining a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER column in another table:

```
TRY_CAST(b.val AS uniqueidentifier) = a.guid_col
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Line 73
>
> String or binary data would be truncated.

The documentation for [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) does say that errors can be thrown in some circumstances:

> However if you request a conversion that is explicitly not permitted, then TRY_CAST fails with an error.

However, a conversion from VARCHAR to UNIQUEIDENTIFIER is allowed by SQL Server:

[image]

I was able to find an example value that throws the error. The value is quite long so I've included in it a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7P5FEbwk). Helpful commenters provided a simpler reproduction of the issue:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX) = REPLICATE(CAST('A' AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 8001);

SELECT TRY_CAST(@s AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);
```

Why does TRY_CAST throw an error instead of returning a NULL value when attempting to convert certain VARCHAR values to UNIQUEIDENTIFIER?

Comment: The question and its answer are useful, but why would anyone want to convert a field bigger than 8000 characters to another type? - varchar(8000) has the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The conversion chart in the documentation doesn't distinguish between `varchar` and `varchar(max)`, though [another section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#large-value-data-types) of the `CAST` and `CONVERT` documentation says:

> #### Large-value data types
>
> Large-value data types have the same implicit and explicit conversion behavior as their smaller counterparts - specifically, the **nvarchar**, **varbinary**, and **varchar** data types. However, consider the following guidelines:
>
> - Conversion from large-value data types, such as **varchar(max)**, to a smaller counterpart data type, such as **varchar**, is an implicit conversion, but truncation occurs if the size of the large value exceeds the specified length of the smaller data type.

Also relevant, from [char and varchar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql#_character):

> When character expressions are converted to a character data type of a different size, values that are too long for the new data type are truncated. The **uniqueidentifier** type is considered a character type for the purposes of conversion from a character expression, and so is subject to the truncation rules for converting to a character type.

When you provide a `varchar(max)` to the `TRY_*` functions with a non-max type as the target, an attempt is made to convert the large value to a non-max string. If that succeeds, all good. If not, you get a *"String or binary data would be truncated."* error because the max string wouldn't fit. This runs counter to the documentation above, which states that truncation occurs.

My own experience is that `max` data types do sometimes have behaviour that doesn't follow the conversion chart or detailed documentation.

This behaviour isn't specific to `uniqueidentifier`, the demo in the question will fail with other types like `bigint` or `date`.

My recollection is that `TRY_*` will work reliably for types compatible with `sql_variant` (which excludes large types). You can also use the try functions to convert among max types, just not always from max to non-max.

It's not ideal from a user experience perspective. I don't know if it is a documentation error or unintended behaviour.

As a workaround, you can convert the LOB text to the length of the string representation of a GUID before attempting the try conversion:

```
DECLARE @s varchar(max) = REPLICATE(CONVERT(varchar(max), 'A'), 8001);

-- No error
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, CONVERT(char(36), @s));
```

Existing [Microsoft feedback item](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/6f6598f1-7e25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0).

Related Q & A:

- [Creating index on computed field: string or binary data would be truncated](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65245/creating-index-on-computed-field-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated/65256#65256)
- [String or binary data would be truncated: Error not caught by TRY_CAST](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61756457)