# TRY_CAST fails when fed very long string... but only from column or variable

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, sql-server-2022

I've recently encountered this weird behavior of [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function, and I wonder what's going on here. (It feels like bug, but most of such bugs I have encountered in past were actually intentional.)

When I use the function on string column or variable longer than 4000 characters, I get an error: *String or binary data would be truncated*.

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX) = REPLICATE('x', 4001); 

SELECT TRY_CAST(@string AS INT);
```

The weird thing is, when I take the literal string and put it into the function, it works fine (it returns NULL).

What is happening here?

I am parsing through a history table, so I need to be able to consume all kinds of strings (and look something up for integer values).

Comment: Related Q & A: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/320855/why-does-try-cast-throw-an-error-when-attempting-to-convert-varchar-to-uniqueide/320884#320884. Some discussion related to this issue can be found in [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143268/try-cast-discussion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql) says "any valid expression," I don't think it's quite true. And unfortunately this is one of those cases where the error message about length happens before `TRY_CAST` is ever able to *gracefully* handle your input.

Even though it is clear that `TRY_CAST` *will* accept strings longer than 4000:

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(TRY_CAST(REPLICATE('x', 4001) AS nvarchar(max)));

----------
8002
```

So it seems the function's ability to gracefully handle the input depends in part on the destination type. It might be that a string constant gets *silently truncated*, similar to:

```
DECLARE @x varchar(1) = 'this is more than one character';
PRINT @x;

----
t
```

But if you tried to put that into a column:

```
CREATE TABLE #x(x varchar(1));
INSERT #x(x) VALUES('this is more than one character');
```

> Msg 2628, Level 16, State 1
> String or binary data would be truncated in table 'tempdb.dbo.#x_...', column 'x'. Truncated value: 't'.
>
> Msg 3621, Level 0, State 0
>
> The statement has been terminated.

Same string input, but handled in very different ways.

Now, it is questionable why you would ever try to cast a string this long to an int in the first place, because the longest a *valid* and *reasonable* value could be would be ~40 characters, e.g.

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(0.00000000000000000000000000000000000001 AS int);
```

If the goal of the code is to convert any string on earth to an `int`, there's really no reason to allow more than 40 characters.

(I guess in theory you could try to cast someone's string input of **π** as an `int`, but, we know the answer is 3, and SQL Server can't express all those decimals anyway - by default `PI()` only returns 15 decimal places.)

If you really can't control the input, then I would simply wrap the argument in `LEFT`, e.g.

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(LEFT(@string, 4000) AS int);
```

You could use a wrapper function and all that, but I don't think you're going to find a simpler workaround. I might suggest instead, though `TRY_CAST` also fails in similar ways here, not handling an overflow:

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(max) = N'222299992929';

SELECT CASE WHEN @string > 40 THEN 'What are you thinking?'
  ELSE CONVERT(varchar(11), TRY_CAST(@string AS int)) END;
```

> Msg 248, Level 16, State 1
> The conversion of the nvarchar value '222299992929' overflowed an int column.

Which has to do with the `CASE` expression and data type precedence, since this works fine:

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(max) = N'222299992929';

SELECT TRY_CAST(@string AS int);

----------
NULL
```

At the end of the day, this is a "doctor, it hurts when I do this" scenario.

Existing Microsoft feedback: [TRY_CAST should not throw error on long values](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/6f6598f1-7e25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0)